# Data structure which supports fast starts_with and like operation on strings

Tags: search, data-structures

Can you suggest me some data structures which will store about 100000 alpha numeric strings?Each string will have an integer X associated with it. The operations that it should efficiently  support are :

  `starts_with(String s)`
  -- return 10 strings that start with string s and have larger X  value that other's.

.

  `like(String x,int start,int end)`        -- return sublist(start,end-1) of all strings that are "like" s.

### other opearions:

  `set_X(s,c)`   --- set X of String s as c.

  `get_x(s)`     --- return X value of s.

  `insert (s,x)` --- create new data entry

  `selete(s,x)`  --- delete an existing entry

DataEntry structure (as u would have already guessed)

```
 {
    string s;
    int x;
 }
```

Comment: What does "like" mean here. Give examples?

Comment: like based on [Levenshtein distance](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLevenshtein_distance&ei=uFs3Ucu_NoKS9QSpwoB4&usg=AFQjCNHIZDhIk5K5Ml7K8baQz3u_o_-1NQ&sig2=Y8QkpQnkV1xKXhFcSa3BEg&bvm=bv.43287494,d.eWU) or something similar to that @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: For like operation ,i have gone through "bk tree algorithm" . will it be efficient for 10^5 nodes?